# datatables fixed column not aligning in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, datatables, bootstrap-modal, fixed

I am working with js datatables. I have a table in modal and I am trying to make make left most column fixed. Below is my script for datatables.

```
$('#table1').DataTable({
"dom": 'Bfrtip',
"bPaginate": false,
"bLengthChange": false,
"bInfo": false,
"bFilter": false,
"buttons": [{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: 'Excel1',
    sheetName: 'Sheet1'
}],
scrollY:        300,
scrollX:        true,
scrollCollapse: true,
paging:         false,
fixedColumns:   true
"ordering": false
});
```

Everything working fine except fixed columns. I have included fixed column css and Js.

The actual problem is, the table gets shrinks when I apply fixed columns.

Comment: Try using [columns.adjust()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) after the modal is displayed.

Comment: @KThorngren It didn't work.

Comment: Do you have `width="100%" in your table tag?

Comment: Yes, the width is 100%. The problem is only with the height. Even if its set the table collapses.

Comment: Maybe you can post the CSS and JS include files you are using.  I would validate you have all the BS files needed against the appropriate FixedColumn example here: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$('#modal_ID').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust();});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have explicitly ' style="width:100%" in table attibute (not in css)